# Did the sailor from USS Theodore Roosevelt die from Covid-19?

Tags: covid-19

> A sailor who was serving aboard the USS Theodore Roosevelt aircraft carrier has become the first on the ship to die from Covid-19, the US Navy announced. [BBC News 13 April 2020](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-52272249)

This seems reasonable until you read farther into the article and see this

> He received twice-daily medical checks and was found unresponsive on Thursday morning. Fellow sailors administered CPR and the sailor was transferred to the navy hospital.

To me it is unimaginable that a patient close enough to death from Covid-19 is so poorly monitored that the health checks are only twice daily.  If he was that critical monitoring should have been much more intense, or the Covid-19 virus is much more aggressive then documented by the CDC.

> Among patients who developed severe disease, the medium time to dyspnea ranged from 5 to 8 days, the median time to acute respiratory distress syndrome (ARDS) ranged from 8 to 12 days, and the median time to ICU admission ranged from 10 to 12 days. [Interim Clinical Guidance for Management of Patients with Confirmed Coronavirus Disease COVID-19 (cdc.gov)](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/hcp/clinical-guidance-management-patients.html#clinical-course)

Comment: "you're in the army now". And you can read the Navy [press release](https://www.navy.mil/submit/display.asp?story_id=112614) yourself. I don't think journalists would be allowed on board to investigate the matter right now... so VTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BBC article is slightly confusing actually. The (shorter) Navy [press release](https://www.navy.mil/submit/display.asp?story_id=112614) has a clearer sequence of events:

> The Sailor, tested positive for COVID-19 March 30, was removed from the ship and placed in an isolation house on Naval Base Guam with four other USS Theodore Roosevelt (CVN 71) Sailors. Like other Sailors in isolation, he received medical checks twice daily from Navy medical teams.
>
> At approximately 8:30 a.m., Apr. 9 (local date), the Sailor was found unresponsive during a daily medical check. While Naval Base Guam emergency responders were notified, CPR was administered by fellow Sailors and onsite medical team in the house. The Sailor was transferred to U.S. Naval Hospital Guam where the Sailor was moved to the Intensive Care Unit (ICU). The Sailor was declared deceased April 13.

So the "twice a day" check was *not* while he was in ICU but before, while he was in the "isolation house". Presumably he was checked more frequently after he was moved to ICU. Also, he was (initially) found unresponsive in what's essentially a "morning call", which probably explains why nobody else noticed his state before. The press release is unclear if the "isolation house" was a common ward or if every sailor was held in a separate room, but even in the former case he might not have been noticed by anyone if he went critical during sleep.

I don't know if the Navy has provided anymore details than this (e.g. at some press conference.)

But since in the title of your question you're skeptical about something else than in the body... here's what the Navy press release said about the cause of death:

> Sailor assigned to the USS Theodore Roosevelt (CVN 71) who was admitted to the Intensive Care Unit (ICU) of the U.S. Naval Hospital Guam April 9 (local date) **died of COVID-related complications** April 13.

---

Also, you are inferring, somewhat incorrectly, from the CDC data that onset of ARDS cannot take the health-care providers by surprise, because of the long time form the onset of "main" illness, i.e. Covid-19.

But there are some [case reports](http://www.annals.edu.sg/pdf/special/OA20057_GohKJ_3.pdf) of patients doing "almost fine" e.g. for 7-8 days and then suddenly developing ARDS, i.e. the progression from "looks mild" to ARDS can be fairly non-linear, so not always easy to predict:

> A 64-year-old Chinese Singaporean man presented with
>   a fall that was preceded by disziness. He also reported a
>   1-week history of fever and a 1-day history of dyspnoea. He had no significant past medical history. He worked as
>   a taxi driver and reported ferrying passengers who were
>   tourists from mainland China in the preceding weeks. He
>   denied any recent travel history or contact with persons
>   with COVID-19. [...]
>
> Real-time reverse transcriptase-polymerase chain
>   reaction (RT-PCR) performed on a throat swab specimen
>   was positive for SARS-CoV-2, and patient was started on
>   lopinavir/ritonavir (Kaletra) on day 2 of hospitalisation.
>
> Over the next 2 days, oxygen saturation was stable
>   on 3 L/min flow of oxygen, and other vital signs were
>   normal apart from a respiratory rate of 18–20 breaths/
>   min. However, on day 3 of hospitalisation (within 48
>   hours of presentation), **he deteriorated rapidly with severe
>   hypoxemic respiratory failure** requiring high flow oxygen
>   supplementation via a face mask. A repeat chest radiograph
>   showed rapid development of bilateral diffuse ground
>   glass opacities (Fig. 1B). He was intubated and initiated
>   on mechanical ventilation. [...]
>
> During his ICU stay, RT-PCR for SARS-CoV-2 (ETT
>   and throat swab specimens) was performed every 2 days.
>   The first negative SARS-CoV-2 RT-PCR was only achieved
>   on day 15 of hospitalisation, approximately 3 weeks from
>   the onset of symptoms. [...]
>
> We describe[d] the clinical course of a COVID-19 patient
>   who rapidly developed ARDS requiring intubation. [...]
>
> Of concern is the rapid clinical deterioration observed
>   in our patient. Together with the threat of a worldwide
>   pandemic and the wide spectrum of clinical severity
>   observed with COVID-19, there is a need for early
>   identification of patients at higher risk of critical illness.
>   Unfortunately, the risk factors and clinical characteristics
>   of ARDS from COVID-19 are still uncertain. What seems
>   consistent. however, is that ARDS and critical illness appear
>   to develop most commonly between 1–2 weeks after the
>   onset of symptoms. Our patient developed ARDS at day
>   9 of symptoms, similar to published studies (Table 2).

So this patient didn't have severe symptoms for a full week basically, but deteriorated to ARDS fairly rapidly, roughly within one day, although wtih some signs of respiratory difficulty 1-2 days ahead of that. And he took roughly a full week in ICU to recover from ARDS.

Interestingly enough, the US sailor was first tested positive for COVID-19 March 30... and he required CPR on Apr 9... which is about 10 days later. This is "right on schedule" for developing ARDS, i.e. it's fairly probable that's what might have happened to him.

Comment: Thank you, that is much more clear then the BBC article and gives a very different impression about how the events transpired.